# Median of values in tuple in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a tuple that contains a few numbers. For example:

```
(a:17, b:14, c:123, d:23, e:37)
```

What is the best way to find the median of the numbers in that tuple? So, for a bag of tuples as above, I should get a bag of single-value tuples, with the single value being the median of the values in one of the input tuples.

Something like this:

```
x = LOAD '/path/to/tuples.csv' USING PigLoader(',') AS (a:int, b:int, c:int, d:int, e:int);
y = FOREACH x GENERATE MEDIAN(a, b, c, d, e);
```

I just don't know how to build the `MEDIAN` function above. I'm hoping I don't need a UDF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEDIAN works on multiple tuples inside a BAG. You would need to create BAG out of a, b, c, d and e and then pass the bag to MEDIAN function.

Comment: Ah, of course! Could I use a literal bag inline? For example, something like `FOREACH x GENERATE id, MEDIAN({a, b, c, d, e});`?

Comment: I dont think it would work. Try using TOBAG function.